# Generating Invoices in Visual Studio 2013 with MS Access (C#)

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2013, ms-access-2013

I need to display data stored in MS Access database as a report (Invoice). I have tried this by creating a .rdlc file and dragging the required data fields from DataSets in DataReport toolbox, but this will display the all the invoice numbers and the data that comes under those Invoice Numbers. So I should be able view one invoice at a time by their invoice number and display data under each invoice number seperately. The data relationships are all set in MS Access. 
To make things clear, My Invoice should have one Invoice Number and display all items that comes under that invoice number and I should also be able to view other Invoices with different Invoice Numbers (Navigation from one invoice to another).

I have not used MS Access much for creating databases, as a requirement for this project I have to use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the data in the report.  Microsoft's example is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252125(v=vs.90).aspx).  The choice of data source shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: It does not show how the navigation should be done. And the source does not direct/give instructions for VS2013( for viewers information) the expressions can be found when you right click on the table/matrix handle on the left side top corner.

Comment: The intended functionality of Report Designer / Reporting Services is ONLY for generating the report.    It doesn't have all the fancy navigation you're describing included in Access, because it's designed to be controlled by its host application (i.e. the application you write).  Access is a *complete application*, Reporting Services is just a *component*.

Comment: Yes. So how can the navigation be implemented with VS2013?